# Duplicate Column Values MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way I can duplicate a column's values into another column?

IE:

```
s_id  img_id
1     -
2     -
3     -
4     -
```

to

```
s_id  img_id
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table SET img_id = s_id;
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Can't believe I didn't think of it... >_<

Comment: is this ok for wordpress wp_usermeta tables, i have a column to that i need to copy